# How can I deploy multiple rails app in nginx with one in the root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, web-deployment

I have two rails apps.Now I want them deployed to

```
app1  /
app2  /app2/
```

is that possible?

I'm using passenger,nginx and rails 3.2

If that's not possible, how can I redirect "/" to "/app1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upstream rails1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

upstream rails2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:7000;
    server 127.0.0.1:7001;
    server 127.0.0.1:7002;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rails1;
    }
    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://rails2;
    }
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#upstream

Comment: how can i use pasenger in this way?

Comment: That's for Nginx. For my example, passenger just needs to be configured to listen to port 8000-8002 for app #1 and 7000-7002 for app #2. I only used rails once but it was extremely easy to make it work on the correct ports.

Comment: Try using thin to run the rails app. -- http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/deployment/nginx-thin